# How to display an action when specifying controller url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering how to display an action when specifying a controller url. For example; say I have DemoController.rb, and views/demo/index.html.erb file. Also I've specified the route in routes.rb
    get 'demo/index'

How can I setup the project so that when I type "localhost:3000/demo" it renders the same layout as "localhost:3000/demo/index"?

Currently when I type in "localhost:3000/demo" I get a "no route matches" error.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `get 'demo' => 'demo#index'` instead for that URL to work.

That said, you might want to use Rails conventions and maybe pluralize the controller and use RESTful routes instead:

`resources :demos, only: :index`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm just beginning to learn Rails, would you mind briefly explaining the difference between the two code snippets you added?

Comment: Routes is a topic on it's own, the second is RESTFul and the other isn't, ultimately both defined the same route. For more information see the routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html